# Find the value from an given equation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am confused about calculating the value A from the following equation:

$$A=1.1A-24000$$

Below are the steps to find A:

*Step 1: Multiply both sides by 10*
$$A\cdot \:10=1.1A\cdot \:10-24000\cdot \:10$$

*Step 2: Refine*
$$A\cdot \:10=11A-240000$$

*Step 3: Subtract 11A from both sides*
$$A\cdot \:10-11A=11A-240000-11A$$

*Step 4: Refine*
$$-A=-240000$$

*Step 5: Divide both sides by -1*
$$\frac{-A}{-1}=\frac{-240000}{-1}$$

*Step 6: Refine*
$$A=240000$$

I don't understand why do we need to multiply both sides by 10 and then subtract 11A from both sides...what is the reason behind this ? It seems like I've missed a couple of important concepts from school but I just couldn't figure out how this works ...

Comment: It's just one way or strategy to do it. The ultimate goal is to get $A$ by itself on one side of the equation, so, you are free to look at the equation and decide how you want to do this. This method multiplies by 10 early on instead of later.

Comment: I hope that $A$ is not a matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to, but it will save you a step later.

You have this:

$$A=1.1A-24000$$

Adding $24000$ and subtracting A from both sides:

$$24000=0.1A$$

Notice you still have to multiply both sides by $10$ to get A.

$$240000=A$$